# Boundary a compact subset of reals means the set is subset of reals too?

Tags: general-topology

I would like some help with the following question please: Let $A$ be a compact set in 
$\mathbb{C}$. I read in some paper that to show that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it suffices to show
that its boundary Fr $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Why is this? it is really irritating me.

Many thanks

Comment: I took an element in $A$ and tried to show it is real using Fr$A$ is real...I need a push, cheers...

Answer (score 1):

If the boundary is empty, then either $A=\emptyset$, or $A=\mathbb{C}$. Assume the boundary is not empty and not contained in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $z\in\partial A$ be non-real. As $\mathbb{C}$ is first countable, there is a sequence $\{z_n\}\subset A$ converging to $z$. But if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then $\{z_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ and thus $z\in\mathbb{R}$, a contradiction.

Comment: @CameronBuie Right, corrected.

Comment: Many thanks Daniel...I want to show that $\partial A\subset \mathbb{R}\Rightarrow A\subset \mathbb{R}$. So let $x$ be in $A$ with $x$ not in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $x$ is not in $A$ ($A$ is closed) and not in int$A$. Then contradiction as we assumed that $x\in A$. Does this look ok? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $x ∈ A \setminus \mathbb{R}$. The set $A ∩ (\mathbb{R} × \{x\})$ is compact, let $y$ be its minimum (with respect to the embedding into $\mathbb{R}$). We have $y ∈ ∂A \setminus \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Very many thanks indeed.